# Selenium Grid+Docker - How to Run my Script on IE

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I have an Application where we need to Certify the Script on IE, I Have implemented the Parallel Execution using Docker for Chrome and Firefox. Any idea how to run on IE since i didn't find any Images for IE.

Regards
Geek

Comment: AFAIK, IE does not have a docker image yet. So you cannot use docker for your IE based test.

Comment: Thanks Much, Can i use PhantomJS for it.